# My jquery tag doesn't work into haml format

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, haml

I have some troubles to include my jquery into my haml file, which I'm new at. 
I Want to include a datepicker and to save the value into a variable

I've include this to my application.js and `gem 'jquery-timepicker-addon-rails'`to my gemfile :

```
//= require jquery-ui
//= require jquery-ui-timepicker-addon 
//= require jquery_ujs
```

Here's what : create a var where I could store a datetime and then substract it to the last_sign_in_at from my user table.

here's what I came up to :

```
-$date =
  %h3 Please enter the following information:
    = form('/search', :post)
      = input(:users, :last_sign_in_at, class: "formbox")
      = submit('Submit', class: "button")

:javascript
  $(function() {
    $( "#start_date, #end_date" ).datepicker({format: 'yyyy-mm-dd'});
  });
```

However, the datepicker doesn't appear and I'm pretty sure something is wrong with my var $date.

Here's the error I have:

```
content can't be both given on the same line as %h3 and nested within it
```

Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is this code:

```
%h3 Please enter the following information:
  = form('/search', :post)
    = input(:users, :last_sign_in_at, class: "formbox")
    = submit('Submit', class: "button")
```

Here you are trying to create `form` inside the `h3` tag which is wrong. It should be like this:

```
%h3 Please enter the following information:
= form('/search', :post) do
  = input(:users, :last_sign_in_at, class: "formbox")
  = submit('Submit', class: "button")
```

You can choose between including content on the same line or nesting it, an error will be raised if both are attempted at the same time. And here in your code you are attempting to do the same (nesting and including at the same time, your text is included and the form is nested). That is why it is throwing error:

```
content can't be both given on the same line as %h3 and nested within it
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, I still get the error `expecting end-of-input` appearing. 
Any thoughts ?

Comment: Add a `do` in front of `form` like this: `= form('/search', :post) do`

Comment: Indeed. Thanks. 
However, I still have some issues to understand how does this datepicker works. I'll try to figure it out myself, thanks a lot.